# Implement Trait for generic caller?

Tags: generics, rust, trait-objects

I was just reading [this article about generics and Traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/generics/gen_trait.html) in the Rust by Example, where they  seem to implement a Trait on a generic caller. Check their article for the full example, but here's a minimal working example:

```rust
struct Example;

trait Foo {
  fn print_foo(&self);
}

impl<T> Foo for T {
  fn print_foo(&self) {
    println!("foo");
  }
}

fn main() {
  let example = Example;
  example.print_foo();
}
```

This example works and prints `foo`. How does this work? For context, I read the full Rust book and didn't see this mentioned until the aforementioned article. How exactly does a generic implementation like this work? How does the compiler know to associate `print_foo` with `Example`? How is this `impl` scoped? Could I have crate-scoped generic implementations?

Comment: It is implemented for every possible type; in this crate, std, and every 3rd party crate.

Comment: It is scoped in the module where it is defined, and anywhere it is imported with `use module::path::to::Foo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How exactly does a generic implementation like this work?

You can more or less think about generics as if they were lazy code generation: `impl<T> Foo for T` means “For *every¹ concrete type* `T`, if an implementation of `Foo` for `T` is needed, create one using this function.”

> How does the compiler know to associate `print_foo` with `Example`?

When the compiler sees a method call, here `.print_foo()`,

- It first looks for a matching inherent impl, `impl Foo { fn print_foo(&self) {...} }`. It doesn't find one in this case.
- It looks at *all traits that are visible in the current scope* (defined or `use`d) to see if any of them define a method called `print_foo`.
- It checks whether `Example` implements any of these traits. `Example` implements `Foo`, because *everything* (except unsized types) implements `Foo`, so that trait is used.

These rules are described in the [Method-call expressions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html) section of the Rust Reference.

> How is this `impl` scoped? Could I have crate-scoped generic implementations?

Trait *implementations* are **not scoped**. They effectively exist everywhere, regardless of what might be brought into the current scope. (The [trait implementation coherence](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/implementations.html#trait-implementation-coherence) rules are designed to ensure that which implementations are found never depends on which crates are in the current crate's dependencies, i.e. which code the compiler compiled.)

However, *traits* are scoped: a trait method will never be found unless the trait is brought into scope with `use` or by defining it in the same module.

In your particular case, `impl<T> Foo for T` means that **it is not possible to write any other implementations for the trait**¹ — there is no such thing as a “crate-scoped generic implementation”.

---

¹ `<T>` does not quite mean “every type”. It means “every *sized* type”, because most generic code can't handle dynamically-sized/“unsized” types like `dyn Foo` and `[i32]`, so it's a useful default restriction. If you write `<T: ?Sized>` instead, then the generic is truly over every possible type.